# Why does the maven Group Id changes from version to another

Tags: maven

I was wondering why the group Id changes in Maven projects from one version to another. Example the project HSQLDB version up to 1.8.0.7:

```
<groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<version>1.8.0.2</version>
```

Afterwards :

```
<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<version>2.2.6</version>
```

The group id changes from `hsqldb` to `org.hsqldb`. Why? It is to warn us that this won't be backward compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely due to mavne1 - maven2 migration, check out [Guide to relocation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html).

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for publishing artifacts changed, there is no other implications to the quality of artifacts with the old conventions.

Sonatype has over time worked on improving the quality of the maven central repository, initially groupId's were not require to match a domain. However, the following contains the current guidelines: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Choosing+your+Coordinates.